# CheckOut API orders in Orders tab?

Tags: square-connect

I'm working with a restaurant that would like a different online ordering experience but want to keep the same workflows they're using in the Square POS with their previous SquareUp.com hosted website.

How do you create an Order that can be seen in the Orders view for the Online Store (web or iPad)?  I have tried using the Checkout API but those orders only appear in the Transactions view and don't show the customer information attached with the Order.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to see API transactions in the Orders view for the Online Store tab in Dashboard. The Online Store tab is utilized for orders that are processed with Square's Free Online Store only. Payments processed through Square APIs will be accessible in the Transactions tab. This is where you can also take actions on API payments, such as refunds.

Furthermore, the Customers API cannot link customers to transactions processed through the Checkout API. You will need to use our Transactions API to link a customer to a transaction using their customer_id that you create with the CreateCustomer endpoint.